How is possible that permalloy magnetic core produce less magnetic field then the iron one?
I'm making a solenoid in the lab to produce magnatic field and trying to use magnetic core for higher field. I tried iron core and permalloy core with the same shape. Surprisingly, the field I got with permalloy core is even less than iron core with the same current. Provided that the permeability of peralloy is much higher, this result is totally unexpected. Could anyone have idea about how it is possible?

That's definitely unexpected, can you edit this to have more information? Dimensions and details about the solenoid, current, how you are measuring the magnetic field, values you are getting for the magnetic field etc.

Since you want a high field, you probably went up to the saturation field strength of the core. Possibly your iron core has a higher saturation than the permalloy (iron could have 1.6 Tesla or more, permalloy perhaps only around 1 Tesla, depending on the precise composition).
The fact that permalloy has a very high permeability does not change the limitation given by the saturation field strength. It would only mean that you need less current to create a certain field in a magnetically closed circuit with permalloy. But since your magnetic circuit most likely is open (field lines going part of their way through the air) even that does not matter, since the air will dominate the effective permeability (you will only get an effective $\mu_r$ in the order of 10 or 100, almost independent of the material used for the core, mostly determined by the shape of the core and the resulting path through the air.)

You are exactly correct. I tried to measure the I-B curve and indeed the permalloy saturate at lower current, which cause this problem.
